# Access solr api using java class

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, solr4, alfresco-webscripts

Can any on tell me how to access solr api using java class.
i want to access **https://localhost:8443/solr4/alfresco/afts?q=DOC_TYPE:UnindexedNode** api using java class.but the problem is that when i am calling with java class its giving **"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found"**.I tried all possible to resolve that. i added certificate in keystore that present in jdk and jre and when i just use a validator to validate then its giving **"pkix path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.suncertpathbuilderexception: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"** .i am using alfresco 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it off, go around it.
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/running-without-ssl.html

Comment: i dont want disable ssl is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out how we connect to Solr in our Trackers. See the solr4-ssl profile in the [solr4 pom](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V5.0.d/root/projects/solr4/pom.xml).  This also may help you: [Alfresco Solr Trackers Showcase](https://ahmedowian.wordpress.com/2016/04/05/alfresco-solr-trackers-showcase/)